# Bypassing ngrok warning page in a browser and console

Tags: ngrok

I was designing a website and would like to host it using ngrok, which I want my clients to scan a QR code to enter it, however the browser warning might give the user a bad experience and might leak my IP address.

I looked up in some other pages in stackoverflow, but they only said to add the header `ngrok-skip-browser-warning: true`. So I added a header using `--request-header-add 'ngrok-skip-browser-warning:true'` in the console. The following is my command `ngrok http 8000 --request-header-add 'ngrok-skip-browser-warning: true'` and is tells me

```
ERROR:  You must specify a single argument: a port or address to tunnel to.
ERROR:  You specified 2 arguments: [8000 true']
ERROR:  For example, to expose port 80, run 'ngrok http 80'.
```

and if I delete the space like `ngrok http 8000 --request-header-add 'ngrok-skip-browser-warning:true'`, the tunnel opened, but the warning still didn't disappear. I've tried Shift+F5 to force reload.
And I'm using a free plan so I can't add edge request header like one answer showed. [can't add header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egvzG.png)

Also I tried using a config file to save and run the setting as follow

```yaml
version: "2"
authtoken: 2RgBb4AnFQ0Ovss1Xec4qeHV7ve_7B1E2EcpcaGssKiW8soPJ
tunnels:
  example:
    proto: http
    addr: 8000
    request_header:
      add: ["ngrok-skip-browser-warning: true"]
    domain: badger-glad-steadily.ngrok-free.app
```

It did start, but showed the warning.

As I mensioned before, bypassing it is for my clients, so I won't be likely to change header in the original request made.
Iwould like to know how could I accomplish bypassing.Thanks.